# Adding a row to datagrid vpf when it contains a collection

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database in Microsoft SQL and a database is connected to it through ADO.Net. I drag the datagrid I need and use it.

Question: How to set a new row when the datagrid already has a collection from the database?

I tried something:

```
userDataGrid.Items.Add (new TableRow ());
```

But it gives an error:

> The operation is not valid when ItemsSource is used. Instead, access
>   and modify items using ItemsControl.ItemsSource.

Comment: What is meant by vpf in your question?

Comment: You need to add the new row to the datasource (like a datatable) instead of the DataGrid.

Comment: wpf - windows presentation foundation

Comment: I have a connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify the items displayed in your datagrid, you must modify the collection which is set as the datagrids itemsource. Be aware that you should use a `ObservableCollection` as your datasource collection in order for the view to update when the collection changes.

Example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding MyDataRows} />
```

Then you modify the displayed items in your backgroundcode / viewmodel like this:

```
this.MyDataRows.Add(itemToAdd);
```

Comment: the fact of the matter is that I have data binding and if I put your example, then my table ceases to bind.

Comment: If your data binding is already working, then just use the bound collection to add items. The way of how to bind to the collection depends on how you set your datacontext. Just make sure the collection you bind to is a ObservableCollection, because otherwise the view will not update if you add items to the collection.